# How to use both json and xml in .net mvc

Tags: json, xml, asp.net-mvc

How to use json or xml specific on api controller/ action?
asp.net MVC5 / Visual studio 2015/ api 2
like

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProduct()
{
    // khai báo array 100 product và trả về
    Product[] product = new Product[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        product[i] = new Product(i);
    }

    return product;
}
```

to return json and the next

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProduct(int id)
    {
        if (id >= 999&&id<=0) return products;
        // truyền id từ client đến, tạo array product có id phần từ
        //sử dùng id vì mặc định url : api/controller/id
        Product[] product = new Product[id];
        for (int i = 0; i < id; i++)
        {
            product[i] = new Product(i);
        }

        return product;
    }
```

return xml?

Comment: What version of asp.net mvc are you using?

Comment: i'm using mvc 5, visual studio 2015

Comment: I guess in MVC 5 this should work out of the box. Have you tried sending a request with accept header? `Accept:  application/xml`